# Display lottery winners

Tags: java, arrays, random, multidimensional-array

I created a lottery program to randomly generate 3 numbers between 0-9 and then randomly generate the 3 winning numbers.  I need help on how to make the program display the winners (if there are some) and display the number of how many won the lottery.

So something like:
Winners:

Person1

person5

Number of winners: 2

Here is my program

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TwoDArray
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] table = new int[50][3];
    int[][] win = new int[1][3];
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = 1;

    // Load the table with values
    for (int row=0; row < table.length; row++)
        for (int col=0; col < table[row].length; col++)
            table[row][col] = rand.nextInt(7-0 +1)+0 + col;

    // Load the winning Values
    for (int row=0; row < win.length; row++)
        for(int col=0; col < win[row].length; col++)
            win[row][col] = rand.nextInt(7-0 +1)+0 + col;

    // Print the table of People
    for (int row=0; row < table.length; row++)
    {
        System.out.print("Person" + i++ +":\t");
            for (int col=0; col < table[row].length; col++)
                System.out.print(table[row][col] + "\t");
                System.out.println();
    }

    //Print the Winning Numbers
    for (int row=0; row < win.length; row++)
    {

        System.out.print("\nThe winning numbers are:\t");
            for(int col=0; col < win[row].length; col++)
                System.out.print(win[row][col] + "\t");
                System.out.println();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: rand.nextInt(7-0 +1) is not syntactically different than rand.nextInt(8) and the latter is easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want another for loop.  Something like:

```
 int counter = 0;
 for (int i =0; i < table.length; i++){
     if (table[i][0] == win[0][0] && table[i][1] == win[0][1] && table[i][2] == win[0][2])
     {
          counter++;
          System.out.println("Person " + i);
     }
 }

 System.out.println("There were " + counter + " winners.");
```